# Is it normal to see a bit of rust under the hood?

Tags: suzuki, rust, hood

While inspecting under the hood of a 2008 Suzuki Swift, I saw a bit of rust in some areas:

[image: Rust 1]

[image: Rust 2]

[image: Rust 3]

(The last image is below/behind the battery.)

I have looked under the hoods of other cars from 2008 and even earlier, but I have not seen anything like this.

Is it problematic?

Comment: I wish my 10 year old car looked this good.  I live where the road salt makes everything rust. I'd say no problems there at all.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call rust "normal".  The term "typical" is probably more correct.  For an 08 model that looks pretty clean.  Either you live someplace without road salt in the winter or you don't drive it in the snow and ice.

Comment: Is this car from the rust belt?  Or from near the ocean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If that is all there is, there is definitely nothing to worry about.

It is just a very mild surface rust and is also on none structural components.

The top one looks like an engine mount which will be made of fairly thick steel, so it would take a very long time to become weakened.

The middle one is just a bracket for the brake ABS solenoids.

The bottom one looks like a bit of bodywork, but again only very mild rust.

For a 14 year old car, it is doing fine.

To slow down the rust you could simply smear a bit of grease on them, or maybe something like waxoyl.

Comment: To fix it, go crazy and get a wire wheel, chuck it in a drill, brush off all the rust and spray on primer and paint. Unless you're selling the car and expecting absolute top dollar for it, that's, um, serious overkill, though.

Comment: I agree. For everything but the chassis, I'd degrease and just coat with hammerite, or similar product.